# tvOS: AVPlayer Audio Plays but there's no video

Tags: swift, video-streaming, audio-streaming, tvos, apple-tv

I have this code as part of a tvOS app

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit


class videoPlayer: UIViewController {

    var thePlayer: AVPlayer?
    var movieToPlay: AVPlayerItem?
    let movieURL="http://trailers.apple.com/movies/independent/walkingwiththeenemy/walkingwiththeenemy-tlr1_720p.mov"

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        let theVideoPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()
        theVideoPlayer.player = thePlayer
        self.addChildViewController(theVideoPlayer)
        self.view.addSubview(theVideoPlayer.view)
        theVideoPlayer.view.frame = self.view.frame
        let movieToPlay = AVPlayerItem(URL: NSURL(string: movieURL)!)
        thePlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: movieToPlay)
        self.thePlayer!.play()
    }
}
```

When the view is loaded the code plays audio but no video.

When one swipes the Apple TV remote a timeline appears with 0:00 duration at the right and 0:00 at the left as the audio plays. There is also a red no-smoking-like sign that appears at the left end of the timeline. My understanding is that the sign means that the video is in the wrong format, but the audio plays (and the clip is from Apple). The video plays plays in other AppleTV apps.

I think the code is correct (it works in another app) and I can't figure out next steps to debug. Can anyone see an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above worked just as expected when I placed it in a separate viewController and then presented it from the viewController where is had resided. I don't understand why, exactly, but it solved the problem video with audio issue.